# Item level targeting error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I am attempting to set up group policies which are applied to OUs containing computers. I am then trying to item level target these policies to OUs containing users.

Whilst attempting to do this, when I select the OU, I am repeatedly given the following error:

[First error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjtd3.png)

This occurs both on a console snap-in on my domain PC, but also when RDP'd into the domain controller itself.

After this error occurs, MMC consistently crashes:

[Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9pWv.png)

My machine is a Windows 7 machine and the domain controller is Server 2008 R2.

I've Googled around for this error but can't find much. I'm loathe to attempt a restart on the server at the moment as we have ~600 concurrent users.

Has anyone seen this error?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find the problem with this: **our AD setup didn't like the slashes in our OU names**.

We had OUs called "Room 10/PCs". Take the forward slash out and the errors disappeared entirely.